# Docker error after CTRL+C: Cannot kill container

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose, next.js

Please help me with the correct Dockerfile for the NextJS application.
I'm trying to use these example from official repository: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile.multistage

My Dockerfile:

```
# Stage 1: Building the code
FROM node:lts-alpine@sha256:5edad160011cc8cfb69d990e9ae1cb2681c0f280178241d58eba05b5bfc34047 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
ENV NODE_ENV production
RUN npm run build
RUN npm ci --only=production
# Stage 2: And then copy over node_modules, etc from that stage to the smaller base image
FROM node:lts-slim@sha256:f07d995a6b0bb73e3bd8fa42ba328dd0481f4f0a4c0c39008c05d91602bba6f1 as production
USER node
ARG PORT
WORKDIR /app
# COPY package.json next.config.js .env* ./
COPY --chown=node:node --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --chown=node:node --from=builder /app/.next ./.next
COPY --chown=node:node --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
EXPOSE $PORT
CMD ["node_modules/.bin/next", "start"]
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
    nextjs:
        container_name: redcross-frontend
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./:/usr/src/app
        env_file:
            - .env.production
```

After execution `docker-compose up` I press CTRL+C for stopping it.
As a result in half of all cases I've faced with the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqS1s.png)

I tried to use `dumb-init` by executing this command: `CMD ["dumb-init", "node_modules/.bin/next", "start"]`.
But I see the same error in half of all cases.

Comment: What problem does this cause? I don't see any. You want to kill container, and it's killed... When you hit ctrl+c, the container's main process exits which in turn terminates the container, so it seem like a race condition: process exits first or docker daemon tries to kill it first.

Comment: It's normal situation and shouldn't be fixed, is it?